# wicket : passing json object from javascript to java

Tags: java, javascript, json, wicket

how can we pass JSON object from Javascript(Client) to Java(Server) ?

i want to access that JSON object in my Java method

Comment: How is obtained the JSON object on client side (with JavaScript)?

Comment: this is my JSON var claimEntryList = {claimEntry:[]};
claimEntryList.claimEntry.push({
entryDate:document.getElementById('datepicker').value ,
entryCategory:document.getElementById('category').value,
entryAmount:document.getElementById('entryAmount').value,
paymentMode:document.getElementById('type').value
});

Answer (score 0):

You can execute any JavaScript by the method:

http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxRequestTarget.html#appendJavaScript%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

AjaxRequestTarget is the result object of a button and a lot of other components.

To receive the JSON on the server side, you will not find a method in Wicket. I think this JSON receiver you will need to code on your own using standard tools like Servlet. GSON is a great Java library to parse JSON to and from Java objects.

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

You can send a JSON object to a Wicket AJAX behavior/component using the parameters and the JavaScript function described here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Wicket+Ajax
However this works with Wicket 6.0. What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Seam remoting. It works pretty well.

you can find an example here: http://tutslink.blogspot.com/2012/10/jsf-tutorials-using-seam-3-remoting.html

You just instantiate your been on client side and execute it's method passing JSON as argument to it.